# How to integrate private GitHub repo with Bluemix devOps service

Tags: git, continuous-integration, ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-cloud-tools

I am trying to build Continuous integration process for deploying blockchain applications into Bluemix  using devOps service.

Currently, this is the setup i have :

1. Application code resided in private GitHub repo.
2. We manually git clone the private repo and deploy the app using the Cloud Foundry "**cf push**" command.

Here is need to automate the app deployment process whenever there is new changes pushed to my private Github repo. **Is there any way we can access the private GitHub repo using the bluemix devOps service and deploy code automatically ?**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using the [IBM Bluemix DevOps services](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/devops/getting-started). I just did it using my own private GitHub repository.

[image: devops landing page]

To set it up I just made a new **Simple Cloud Foundry toolchain** using the third-party GitHub integration. It prompted me for access to both my private and public GitHub repos.

After setting that up, Bluemix created a delivery pipeline which subsequently builds and deploys my app to Bluemix on each git commit:

[image: my toolchain]